# mongodb aggregation query, using projection, $size,$split

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

i have to make a query, so in my query i must to show only  when the size is one; and in my projection i show the results , and i have the query but only show all the sizes, but i only need to show when the size is one, i ve no idea how to make it. and i used a projection.
this is a single doc:
[document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TBzST.png)

and my query is this:

```
db.movies.aggregate([
{"$project":
  {
    "_id": 0,
    "longi":{$size:{ $split: [ "$title", " " ]}}
  }
    }]);
```

and the result is this:

```
{ "longi" : 2 }

{ "longi" : 2 }

{ "longi" : 6 }

{ "longi" : 11 }

{ "longi" : 2 }

{ "longi" : 2 }

{ "longi" : 6 }

{ "longi" : 2 }

{ "longi" : 1 }

{ "longi" : 4 }

{ "longi" : 5 }

{ "longi" : 3 }

{ "longi" : 5 }

{ "longi" : 3 }

{ "longi" : 3 }

{ "longi" : 5 }

{ "longi" : 4 }

{ "longi" : 5 }

{ "longi" : 1 }
```

[res](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLZ0D.png)
but i just want to show  when the size is one

Comment: You are presently doing a course at MongoDB University with this question. The spirit of the course is that you "think" about how to answer the question instead of asking others to solve it for you. The course material will reveal the answer when then unit is complete anyway. But since it is not desirable that others may come along and simply be able to look up the answer to the question, we ask that you remove this question and do not attempt asking for answers published in public forums.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `$match` after `$projetct`.

```
db.movies.aggregate([
{"$project":
  {
    "_id": 0,
    "longi":{$size:{ $split: [ "$title", " " ]}}
  }
 }
 , {$match: {"longi":1 }}
 ]);
```

Comment: Can you please pay attention to the comment above. You are publishing an answer to course material. Just like the question, the preference is that you do not do that.